# Is there a way to retrieve the next best optimal solution in PuLP?

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I have a very simple knapsack problem listed below.

The sample of the df looks like this:

```
| weight | item  | profit |
|--------|-------|--------|
| 1      | item1 | 3.977  |
| 2      | item2 | 3.126  |
| 3      | item3 | 2.698  |
| 4      | item4 | 2.607  |
| 5      | item5 | 2.569  |
```

The objective is to maximize profit while choosing four items with a combined weight >=10. My code to solve is the following:

```
prob = LpProblem("Weight",LpMaximize)
player_vars = [pulp.LpVariable(f'Item_{row.item}', cat='Binary') for row in df.itertuples()]

# total items  constraint
prob += pulp.lpSum(player_var for player_var in player_vars) == 4

# total weight constraint
prob += pulp.lpSum(df.Seed.iloc[i] * player_vars[i] for i in range(len(df))) >= 10

# problem
prob += pulp.lpSum([df.profit.iloc[i] * player_vars[i] for i in range(len(df))])

# solve and print the status
prob.solve()
print(LpStatus[prob.status])
    
#print results
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if player_vars[i].value() == 1:
            row = df.iloc[i]
            print(row.item, row.weight,row.profit)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to obtain the second best answer and so on using PuLP?
Thanks!

Comment: One way to do this would be to re-solve the problem with an additional constraint added to forbid the existing best solution. For example say the solutions to the original problem are stored as `player_vars_soln`, you would then add a constraint: `pulp.lpSum(player_vars_soln[i]*player_vars[i] for i in range(len(df))) <= 3`

Comment: @kabdulla has answered the question (shouldn't really be a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to re-solve the problem with an additional constraint added to forbid the existing best solution. For example say the solutions to the original problem are stored as `player_vars_soln`, you would then add a constraint:

`prob += pulp.lpSum(player_vars_soln[i]*player_vars[i] for i in range(len(df))) <= 3`